# How to mock PropertiesFactoryBean using Powermock? This bean is injected as a property in another bean

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

Im trying to mock a bean which is actually injected as a property in the class I'm writing Unit tests on. 
Here is the snippet
**beans.xml:**

```
 <bean id="mcgProperties"    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
          <list>
              <value>classpath:mcg.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
  </bean>

<bean id="summary" class="com....client.SummaryServiceImpl">
      <property name="propMap" ref="mcgProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Im writing Unit tests for SummaryServiceImpl.
And Im stuck at

```
propMap = PowerMockito.mock(Properties.class);
mcgProperties = PowerMockito.mock(PropertiesFactoryBean.class);
**when(mockAppContext.getBean("mcgProperties"), PropertiesFactoryBean.class).thenReturn(mcgProperties);**
```

I get an error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The object to perform the operation on cannot be null."

Comment: What is `mockAppContext`? Note that you could probably use real objects here, see [`PropertiesLoaderSupport`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html)

Comment: mockAppContext is mocking the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class mockAppContext = PowerMockito.mock(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.class);

Comment: So if you are mocking the whole context, then why on earth are you mocking the content as well? Also if this is for the purpose of testing the `SummaryServiceImpl` then just create an instance and inject a `Properties` instance into it. Also the call to `getBean("")` would result in a `Properties` object and not the actual `PropertiesFactoryBean`. Seems to me you are just mocking way to much...

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the suggestion. I didnt need to mock the content.. Using this code worked: 
'code' mcgProperties = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
           mcgProperties.setLocations(new ClassPathResource[]{new ClassPathResource("mcg.properties")});
          mcgProperties.afterPropertiesSet();

          propMap = mcgProperties.getObject();
        industrySummaryService.setPropMap(propMap); 'code'